# Convert clauses to CNF

Tags: java, conjunctive-normal-form

I want to transform my clauses to conjuctive normal form. Clauses are changed each time i run my program, so i guess i need to built-in a tool in my program to do this for me. Is there any suggestionn how to implement this?? i also found some libraries like:
[Orbital library](http://symbolaris.com/orbital/Orbital-doc/api/orbital/moon/logic/ClassicalLogic.Utilities.html#conjunctiveForm(orbital.logic.imp.Formula)). I am new to logic programming and i have never used them so, its quite difficult to get through them. I also tried to find an example to clear things up, but nothing came up. I am builting my program in java language. Please help...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

can you use some of this code? 
http://aima-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/aima-core/src/main/java/aima/core/logic/fol/CNFConverter.java

# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://aima-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ aima-java-read-only